# Seagate Blackarmor NAS Shared folder recovery

Tags: network-share, network-attached-storage, data-recovery, seagate

We have a Seagate Blackarmor NAS on which we have some shared folders. Yesterday, suddenly the shared folders were not being shown while trying to access as Windows share. We have CIFS and FTP enabled but those folders can't be accessed from anywhere. Even the web console does not show those folders. However, the web console shows that there is disk usage(14%) and it can identify the types of files. Even the volume on which the shared folders were created is showing it's status as "Good".

There are 4 disks and the status of them is showing as "Good" although earlier it was showing as "Failed" for two disks on which the volume was created. After a reboot from the web console, the status started showing as "Good".

My question is, is there any way to recover those data from the shared folders? The disks are SATA disks. There is a "migrate" option to other two disks. If we migrate the data, will it be possible to access them?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

These NAS devices often manipulate files when they update and manage the data. A fact is that the data never really gets deleted so you recover the data through any RAID data recovery tool. It seems like the drives are SAS based so you’ll need to connect those to the computer in order get them recognized by the data recovery software (Source out a SAS Controller from one of the online stores like Newegg, also remember to get the information on which raid level your NAS device is running on ). If its raid 0,5 or raid 6 based then you can recover the data through recovery tools like stellar phoenix windows data recovery technician or ufs explorer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The disks were actually SATA disks which were wrongly recorded as SAS. We recovered the data by attaching the disk to a linux machine.